# Got 2 user folders in /home after reinstall | But only one user

Tags: 14.04, 15.10, downgrade

So, a few months ago, I downgraded form 15.10 to 14.04 by re-installing ubuntu, (Saved everything in /home, just re-mounted it), but in my haste, I accedently changed user name. 
No biggie, except now i have 1 user folder I'm unable to remove.

I've tried the following:

```
sudo rm -r /home/"user"
sudo rm -f /home/"user"
sudo rm -fr /home/"user"
```

I get the following back :

```
rm: can not remove ”/home/robin/.wine-pipelight/drive_c/users/robin/Local Settings/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/UHU9SPYJ”: operation is not permitted
```

The folder is empty except for this ".wine-pipelight" folder, and there is really no problem with this, it just enoys me that it's there. 
So if anyone has any idea's, I'm open to it!

Comment: boot to recovery mode and delete it from the command line or delete it from a live CD.

Comment: Didn't work in either init 1 or recovery, thanks anyway!

Comment: try doing `lsattr /home/robin/.wine-pipelight/drive_c/users/robin/Local\  Settings/Temporary\ Internet\ Files/Content.IE5/*`. My theory is that an immutable flag was somehow set. If the output of that has an "i" in it, then you can do `sudo chattr -R -i /home/robin` to remove the flag, then you can remove the folder.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do the trick either. Got no output from that. 
Tried "sudo chattr -R -i /home/robin" anyway, and then rm -R /home/robin but no luck. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -R 'folder_name'
```

With me it worked. 
If it doesn't work, try this one:

```
sudo rm -Rfv 'folder_name'
```

or

```
userdel -r 'user_name'
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-remove-user-command/

Comment: Thanks, but none of what you recommended worked in either init 1, deufalt init, or recovery mode. 
It that freakin ".wine-pipelight" folder that says I don't have permission to remove it. And it's not even active! 
I'm almost going crazy over here, Nothing works.